# Why is Kafka connect light weight?

Tags: apache-kafka, streaming, spark-streaming, apache-nifi, apache-kafka-connect

I have been working with kafka connect, Spark streaming , Nifi with kafka for streaming data.

I am aware that unlike other technologies kafka connect is not a separate application and it is a tool of kafka.

In case of distributed mode all technologies implement the parallelism by the underlying tasks or threads. What makes kafka connect to be efficient when dealing with kafka and why is it called light weight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's efficient and lightweight because it uses the built-in Kafka protocols and doesn't require an external system such as YARN. While it is arguably better/easier to deploy Connect in Mesos/Kubernetes/Docker, it is not required

The connect API is also maintained by the core Kafka developers rather than people that just want a simple integration into another tool. For example, last time I checked, NiFi cannot access the Kafka message timestamps. And dealing with the Avro Schema Registry seems to be an after thought in the other tools as compared to using Confluent Certified Connectors